# How to identify different types automatically using Jackson mapper

Tags: java, json, jackson, mapping, dto

I have a simple situation. I have a main DTO class with the following fields:
**AnimalDTO**

```
public class AnimalDTO {
    @JsonCreator
    public AnimalDTODTO(@JsonProperty("error") boolean error,
                                       @JsonProperty("errorMessage") String errorMessage,
                                       @JsonProperty("cat") CatDTO cat,
                                       @JsonProperty("dog") DogDTO dog) {
        this.error = error;
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
        this.cat = cat;
        this.dog = dog;
    }

    private boolean error;
    private String errorMessage;
    private CatDTO cat;
    private DogDTO dog;
}
```

**CatDTO:**

```
public class CatDTO {
    @JsonCreator
    public CatDTO(@JsonProperty("catNumber") String catNumber,
                  @JsonProperty("catState") String catState) {
        this.catNumber = catNumber;
        this.catState = catState;
    }

    private String catNumber;
    private String catState;
}
```

**DogDTO:**

```
public class DogDTO {
    @JsonCreator
    public DogDTO(@JsonProperty("dogNumber") String dogNumber,
                  @JsonProperty("dogState") String dogState
                  @JsonProperty("dogColor") String dogColor
                  @JsonProperty("dogBalance") BigDecimal dogBalance) {
        this.dogNumber = dogNumber;
        this.dogState = dogState;
        this.dogColor = dogColor;
        this.dogBalance = dogBalance;
    }

    private String dogNumber;
    private String dogState;
    private String dogColor;
    private BigDecimal dogBalance;

}
```

and from external API I have responses (and I can't change it) for **dog** like:

```
{
   "dogNumber": "23",
   "dogState": "good",
   "dogColor": "pink",
   "dogBalance": 5
}
```

and for **Cat**:

```
{
   "catNumber": "1",
   "catState": "good"
}
```

And I want to use Jackson mapper like this: `objectMapper.readValue(stringJson, AnimalDTO.class);`

I was thinking to add in **AnimalDTO**:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
  property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({ 
  @Type(value = CatDTO.class, name = "cat"), 
  @Type(value = DogDTO.class, name = "dog") 
})
```

but it's not working.

How to handle my case in best way?

Comment: You showed us the cat json and the dog json...do you have a an animal json? Or are these 2 JSONS completely independent??

Comment: @SMA - No, I dont have an animal json...these 2 JSONS completely  independent

Comment: then if I am not mistaken, you need to create a DTO for each and you can't use `JsonTypeInfo`.  Based on my understand `JsonTypeInfo` and `JsonSubTypes` are used when you have inheritance in your JSONs.  In your case each JSON has completely different variables....

Comment: Since two classes are independent (no inheritance hierachy) you don't need `@JsonTypeInfo` nor `@JsonSubTypes`. You can directly serialize/deserialize **animal json** to `AnimalDTO` which will have `CatDTO` and `DogDTO` respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will work just fine (without any `@JsonTypeInfo` or `@JsonSubTypes` annotations) if the JSON that you get from the external API is as follows:

```json
{
  "dog": {
    "dogNumber": "23",
    "dogState": "good",
    "dogColor": "pink",
    "dogBalance": 5
  },
  "cat": {
    "catNumber": "1",
    "catState": "good"
  }
}
```

If this does not look similar to the JSON you receive then you need to add it to your answer so that we can help you further.